# How to calculate speed using accelerometer in ios

Tags: ios, performance, cllocationmanager

I want to implement a functionality to calculate the speed of moving object, but I don't want to use GPS`(CLLocationManager`).

Any suggestions on other ways to calculate speed?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153159/calculate-speed-from-accelerometer

Answer (score 2):

> I want to implement a functionality to calculate speed of moving object, but I don't want to using GPS(CLLocation).

An object traveling at constant velocity doesn't experience any forces for the accelerometer to measure, so the accelerometer alone isn't enough to determine velocity -- you can only measure changes in velocity. If you know the initial velocity, like if the user tells you that the phone is at a standstill, then you can monitor acceleration and use that to determine velocity. That's likely to be quite error-prone, however, and the error will accumulate over time so that your velocity measurement will become less and less accurate.

There might be other ways to measure speed, like taking several photos with the camera and trying to determine speed from the changes in the images. Or you could measure *average* speed between two known points by observing the time between leaving one known wifi SSID and reaching another. But the right way to determine velocity is really to use the Location Manager.

Comment: so basically if I hold my phone still in the car I won't be able to use accelerometer data to calculate speed correct?

Comment: @MaksimKniazev In order to keep track of speed using the accelerometer, you'd need to know the initial speed and also keep track of all accelerations. But doing it that way is like keeping track of your position by [dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) -- OK for estimating over short periods, but very error-prone over longer periods. You'd be much better off getting your speed from the GPS.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. But funny Engineers from Apple emailed me saying use Accelometer instead of GPS ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️