# How to calculate speed and distance from acceleration in iOS

Tags: ios, physics, accelerometer

Okay, this is an odd one - and the question has been asked before in various guises and always closed out with the opinion that a) it won't be accurate and b) that it will get less accurate with time.

I understand this - but I'm doing an experiment to see whether that accuracy can be boosted at all by taking into account other evidential sources (for example, if a map has been plotted in advance then the direction of travel from the compass combined with the route could provide another evidence source).

The problem is that my code is clearly rubbish - so I'd welcome your opinion.  I suspect that this might be a brown paper bag error!

My **ViewController.h** looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate> {

    UIAccelerometer *accelerometer;

    long last_speed;
    long distance_travelled;

    long lastAccel;
    long long lastTime;

    IBOutlet UITextField* speedView;
    IBOutlet UITextField* distanceView;
}

@end
```

And my **ViewController.m** looks like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    lastAccel = 0;
    last_speed = 0;
    distance_travelled = 0;
    lastTime = (long)(NSTimeInterval)([NSDate.date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);

    accelerometer = UIAccelerometer.sharedAccelerometer;
    accelerometer.updateInterval = 0.1;
    accelerometer.delegate = self;
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)meter
        didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    long long currentTime = (long)(NSTimeInterval)([NSDate.date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);
    long long deltaTime = currentTime - lastTime;
    lastTime = currentTime;

    long accel_x = acceleration.x;
    long accel_y = acceleration.y;
    long accel_z = acceleration.z;

    long integrated_acceleration = sqrtl(accel_x*accel_x + accel_y*accel_y + accel_z*accel_z);

    long average_acceleration = (lastAccel + integrated_acceleration) / 2;

    long speed = last_speed + (average_acceleration * deltaTime);
    long average_speed = (speed + last_speed) / 2;
    distance_travelled = distance_travelled + (average_speed * deltaTime);

    last_speed = speed;
    lastAccel = integrated_acceleration;

    [speedView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", speed]];
    [distanceView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", distance_travelled]];
}

@end
```

When the code is run, the speed and the distance keep going up continually, and deceleration (me slowing down) is never taken into account - so even when I stop, speed and distance keep going up.

Even by the standards of 'this will be a bit inaccurate' that's taking it too far!

All thoughts and opinions gratefully received (well almost - I *know* that it won't be accurate!)

Comment: What’s the real world problem here? If you want to know speed and distance of actual travel, Core Location will tell you, and if you want to track a gesture (like a Wii) Core Motion will tell you, so what’s the accelerometer doing in the story?

Comment: Plus, UIAccelerometer was deprecated years ago, plus it includes gravity (which never stops, even if you do), so without a filter your results are meaningless. See http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch35.html#_raw_acceleration

Comment: The real world problem is that most iPads and all iPod Touches have no GPS functionality - so if I want to estimate (very roughly is fine) speed, I need to find another way.

Comment: Well, that's a good answer (and I sort of suspected it). :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't calculate Speed using UIAccelerometer.

Please find the link for more clarification : [How to calculate speed using accelerometer in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315436/how-to-calculate-speed-using-accelerometer-in-ios)

Comment: Yup - that was one of the articles that I was reading.  The key point there is * If you know the initial velocity, like if the user tells you that the phone is at a standstill, then you can monitor acceleration and use that to determine velocity. That's likely to be quite error-prone, however, and the error will accumulate over time so that your velocity measurement will become less and less accurate.*  I accept that - which is why I said that this will be merely one point of evidence.